# Python ImportError: No module named djng

Tags: django, django-angular

Not sure what is the correct package to be installed. When I do pip install djng I get this error message.

```
pip install djng
Collecting djng
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djng (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for djng
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out it was `pip install django-angular` but strangely It was installed already.

I just tried to uninstall and install it again which got it working.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html